# what does a FLOW ERROR (BAD TRACE PACKET ON D-SIDE) indicate in Trace32?

Tags: debugging, arm, trace32, lauterbach

I am using the external debugger Lauterbach to collect traces from the arm - M7 via coresight through the JTAG ports. While collecting the traces for the program loaded, the GUI of T32 displays FLOW ERROR (BAD TRACE PACKET ON D-SIDE) while stepping through the program. This is seen when the etm.dataTrace is set to anything except OFF.

What could this error mean?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bad trace packet means in general that the trace decoder gets some ETM data, which is not known by the decoder at all. If the trace is transferred to the debug tool via dedicated parallel port (TPIU), this may be caused by electrical issues like crosstalk or bad terminations.
It can also happen if your CPU core is newer than your TRACE32 version.

I recommend that you contact the Lauterbach support hotline for your specific request.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Does the TRACE32 perform a data check as in expected_data vs obtained_data on the trace packets?

Comment: That does not happen automagically. How should a generic debugger know the expected data in general? But I think you can write scripts for TRACE32 to perform such tests specifically to your application.